# Apache NiFi: Creating a new column by comparing multiple rows with various data

Tags: csv, apache-nifi

I have a csv which looks like this:

```
first,second,third,num1,num2,num3
12,312,433,0787388393,0783452323,01123124
12,124345,453,07821323,077213424,0123124421
33,2432,214,077213424,07821323,0234234211
```

I have to create another column according to the data stored in `num1` and `num2`. There can be various values in the columns but the new column should only contain 2 values it's either `original` or `fake`. (I should only compare the first 3 digits in both `num1 and`num2`.

For the mapping part I have another csv which looks like this (I have many more rows):

```
078,078,fake
072,078,original
077,078,original
```

My Output csv should look like this after mapping:

```
first,second,third,num1,num2,num3,status
12,312,433,0787388393,0783452323,01123124,fake
12,124345,453,07821323,072213424,0123124421,original
33,2432,214,078213424,07821323,0234234211,fake
```

Hope you can suggest me a nifi workflow to get the following done:

Answer (score 1):

You can use `LookupRecord` for this, but due to the special logic you'll likely have to write your own `ScriptedLookupService` to read in the mapping file and compare the first 3 digits.

Comment: Is it possible for you to be more descriptive of the workflow and the properties that have to be changed.